# How to create a legend for every subplot in a cycle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the subplots,and i'm trying to set the legend for every subplot:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize = (20,20))
for el in dict_for_genders['Means']:
    ax[0,0].plot(['Chapter ' + str(x) for x in range(1,7)],dict_for_genders['Means'][el])

for el in dict_for_genders['Count_viewers']:
    ax[0,1].plot(['Chapter ' + str(x) for x in range(1,7)],dict_for_genders['Count_viewers'][el])

for key,value in dict_for_genders['Count fans Star wars'].items():
    ax[1,0].hist(x = key, weights = value)

for key,value in dict_for_genders['Count fans Star Trek'].items():
    ax[1,1].hist(x = key, weights = value)

for each_ax in ax:
    each_ax.legend(['Male','Female'])
```

I have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ML/DataQuest/DataCleaning/Star wars project/star_wars_project.py", line 244, in <module>
    each_ax.legend(['Male','Female'])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'legend'
```

How can i set the legend for every axes in a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax` is a 2D array with shape (2, 2). Therefore, `each_ax` is a 1D array with shape (2,). You have to access every element separately. For example:

```
for row in ax:
    for each_ax in row:
        each_ax.legend(['Male', 'Female'])
```